# Ionic add a click function to dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

From my code I have a function that can create div elements multiple times (with `surroundContents()`), how can I make these created div elements to trigger a function inside the class of the very same page?

More precisely, I need that any of these div elements (created with function `createDiv()`) be able to trigger with click the function called `clickCreatedDiv(arg)` located in `MyPage class` and pass any string as an argument. I have tried this `element.setAttribute('(click)', 'clickCreatedDiv()');` but with no success. How can I achieve this behavior?

```
export class MyProvider {
  wrapSelection(comment) {
    let element = document.createElement("div")
    element.setAttribute('(click)', 'clickCreatedDiv()');
    element.surroundContents(element);
  }
}

import { MyProvider } from '../../providers/my-provider';
@Component({
    selector: 'page-mypage',
    templateUrl: 'mypage.html',
}) 
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public myprovider: MyProvider) {}
  createDiv() {
    this.myprovider.wrapSelection();
  }

  clickCreatedDiv(arg) { // This is what I want to trigger with click
    alert('click ' + arg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `setAttribute('onclick', 'clickCreatedDiv()')`

Comment: @KoshVery that makes me get the message 'clickCreatedDiv is not defined'.

Comment: It means that `onclick` works, now you have to reach the function. Probably `MyPage.clickCreatedDiv()` would work?

Comment: Not yet, now MyPage is not defined. Even when I'm importing it within MyProvider. Something must be missing...

Comment: `onclick` attribute function should be available from the global scope. Otherwise it would be better to set the event handler in that scope where `clickCreatedDiv` is available.

Comment: What string do you want to pass as an argument to `clickCreateDiv`? Is it the `comment` parameter of `wrapSelection(comment)`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan it would be an attribute from the same div, however, I didn't include it in my question for not making it too long, but only to expect an answer compatible with the usage of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular event binding syntax `(click)="doSomething()"` cannot be used to set the event handler on a dynamically created HTML element. To make it work, you can pass the event handler from the `MyPage` class, and set it with `element.addEventListener`:

```
export class MyProvider {
  wrapSelection(eventHandler) {
    let element = document.createElement("div")
    element.addEventListener("click", () => { eventHandler("Some text"); });
    ...
  }
}
```

In `MyPage`, the event handler should be defined as an arrow function to preserve `this` and allow to access the class members:

```
createDiv() {
  this.myProvider.wrapSelection(this.clickCreatedDiv);
}

clickCreatedDiv = (arg) => {
  alert('Clicked: ' + arg);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbc2x) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the click function as a callback to wrapSelection.
E.g. something like:

```
export class MyProvider {
  wrapSelection(comment, onClick) {
    let element = document.createElement("div")
    element.setAttribute('(click)', onClick);
    element.surroundContents(element);
  }
}

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public myprovider: MyProvider) {}
  createDiv() {
    this.myprovider.wrapSelection('Some comment', this.clickCreatedDiv);
  }

  clickCreatedDiv(arg) { // This is what I want to trigger with click
    alert('click ' + arg);
  }
}
```

Comment: setAttribute('(click)', onClick) generates this error: "String contains an invalid character".

Comment: But using, setAttribute('onclick', onClick) renders this: <div onclick="function (arg) {alert('click ' + arg);}"></div>, but clicking it shows this error: function statement requires a name

Comment: Hmmm, what if you try: element.addEventListener("click", onClick);